# TypeScript: Omit readonly object literal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, object, object-literal

I need to ensure that the value of `bar` must be a key of readonly object `FOO` except the key `c`.

#### Code

```
const FOO = {
  a: {
    // key-value pairs
  },
  b: {
    // key-value pairs
  },
  c: {
    // key-value pairs
  },
} as const;

// all of the keys are assignable
const allKeys: keyof typeof FOO = 'a';

// tried this but TypeScript doesn’t throw error
const bar: Omit<keyof typeof FOO, 'c'> = 'c';
```

Comment: Please don't ask more than one question per question, post a new one (and provide a link to this one if it's related) :)

Comment: Sure, got it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Omit<T, K>` is for objects/records and properties, you're looking for `Exclude<T, U>` which works for unions:

```
const bar: Exclude<keyof typeof FOO, 'c'> = 'c'; // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAYgeQTAvDA3gKBjAhgLg2xxgHpSYBrAUwE8BaAN1wBsBXamAB1wEsAnCMQC%20AGmIAjQlhJkKNBs3aceAoTjHFg04jnJU6TVh259BI8cLwQYoSFADcmTPtYsYIAGYwoAC04KNrj8nLgQELwA5mC4EizUmHbQeCwsANJ0EIQKXj60XNS5iMhoAOS4pU4uFFD8vNQAJj6%20vDYSbLAAKvnUAMrAdVywDSDUEGCAmASwfvwgAO4w1Pyz-IngyRLBhACiAB7A7A3UADw53lA9RUiiMKXApQB8qLf3DnKLyyD8QA)

Alternatively, apply the `Omit` on the record type, and then apply `keyof` on the result:

```
const bar: keyof Omit<typeof FOO, 'c'> = 'c'; // error
```

Comment: `typeof FOO` is a record type (or an object type), `keyof typeof FOO` is a union type of all the keys, that's what the `keyof` operator does. `keyof typeof FOO` is `'a' | 'b' | 'c'`, a union between the literal types `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'`.

Comment: Got it. And why does TS not throw an error in case I try to `Exclude` or `Extract` a key which is not even present in the union, e.g. `Exclude<keyof typeof FOO, 'd'>`?